# Corrupted Ambiance Theme

Tags: ambiance

I have a corrupted Ambiance theme... the background of the top menus is grey :( i must have done some fiddling...

If i choose another theme, it seems to work fine, but I want Ambiance :D what do you think i could try?

I already tried downloading ambiance again, but same issue happens. I tried to download gnome color chooser, but it doesn't do nothing, so i guess maybe i can change something else... but where?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Create another user account ,and  then check problem exists or not

Comment: problem persists!

Comment: Actually problem is there if i use gnome3 too, in some way. SOmetimes the window topbar is corrupted... it's driving me crazy. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 12.04 beta? And if so..are you using Classic Gnome? Because then you smashed into a bug. If not..try reinstalling light themes (sudo apt-get remove light-themes).

Comment: no i'm on 11.10! i'M now trying to reinstall light-themes